# Get all rows before and n rows after a specific value within group

Tags: sql, r, conditional-statements, extract

I am looking for a simple R/SQL code which does the following. Within a specific firm, it looks for the first instance of 1 in the VALUE column, it then

1. extracts all rows before that (which would all have 0 in the VALUE column) and
2. exactly two rows after that as long as those two rows have the VALUE 0.

The code does this for all firms.

so this table....

```
----------------------
| FIRM | YEAR | VALUE |
----------------------
|  A   | 2007 |  0   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2008 |  0   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2009 |  0   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2010 |  1   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2011 |  0   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2012 |  0   |
----------------------
|  B   | 2009 |  0   |
----------------------
|  B   | 2010 |  1   |
----------------------
|  B   | 2011 |  0   |
----------------------
|  C   | 2010 |  0   |
----------------------
|  C   | 2011 |  1   |
----------------------
|  C   | 2012 |  1   |
----------------------
```

would look like this...

```
--------------------------
| FIRM  | YEAR  | VALUE  |
--------------------------
|  A   | 2007 |  0   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2008 |  0   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2009 |  0   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2010 |  1   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2011 |  0   |
----------------------
|  A   | 2012 |  0   |
----------------------
```

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R, you can create a function that will return the row numbers to be selected.

```
get_rows <- function(VALUE) {
   ind <- which(VALUE == 1)[1]
   if ((ind + 2) <= length(VALUE) && all(VALUE[c(ind + 1,ind + 2)] == 0))
     sort(c(which(VALUE[seq_len(ind + 2)] == 0), ind))
   else 0
}
```

and apply it for each `FIRM`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(FIRM) %>% slice(get_rows(VALUE))

#  FIRM   YEAR VALUE
#  <fct> <int> <int>
#1 A      2007     0
#2 A      2008     0
#3 A      2009     0
#4 A      2010     1
#5 A      2011     0
#6 A      2012     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(FIRM = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
YEAR = c(2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L), VALUE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, Thank you offering this solution. I tried it on my sample and it throws the following error-"Error in seq_len(ind + 2) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer". Would know what the issue is?

Comment: @M1001 Looks like you have certain `FIRM` in which there is not even single 1. What would you like to do in such case?

Comment: Hi Ronak, So I fixed the previous issue. I made sure that I have a sample in which there is at least one 1. The code now runs. However, it is even including cases where there aren't two 0's after the first 1. So it is including cases where there are 0's before the 1, but nothing after. Could you please modify the code to ensure that it only picks cases where mandatorily are two 0's after the 1. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @M1001 So if there are 0's before 1 and no 2 0's after 1, you don't want to include any row or just ignore the next rows after 1? For example what would be output for group "B" and "C" in your example? No rows will be selected for them/?

Comment: Hi Ronak, Precisely. If there aren't two 0's after the first instance of 1, then the entire FIRM should be ignored. It is ok to not have any 0's before the 1, but there must be exactly two 0's after the 1. It is for this reason that IN the example above, only A get picked. B and C don't since they dont have 2 0's after the 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the minimum year and then use this information:

```
with t as (
      select firm, min(year) as min_year_1
      from tab t
      where value = 1
      group by firm
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by firm order by year) as prev_value,
             lead(value) over (partition by firm order by year) as next_value
      from tab t
     ) t join
     tt
     on tt.firm = t.firm
where t.year <= tt.min_year or
      (t.year = tt.min_year + 1 and
       t.value = 0 and
       t.next_value = 0
      ) or
      (t.year = tt.min_year + 2 and
       t.value = 0 and
       t.prev_value = 0
      );
```

That last condition on both rows after being `0` is rather tricky.

This assumes that the year are consecutive with no gaps, which is consistent with the data in your question.

EDIT:

You can do this just with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by firm, running_value) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by firm, running_value) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(value) over (partition by firm order by year) as running_value
            from tab t
           ) t
      ) t
where running_value = 0 or
      (running_value = 1 and seqnum = 1) or  -- first "1"
      (running_value = 1 and seqnum <= 3 and
       cnt >= 3);
```

Comment: Note on the CTE: Not sure if that would work with `sqldf` in R.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the code. If my table name is TAB, should I be replacing t and tt with TAB. Also should'nt "min_year_1" actually be "min_year". Thanks for helping out with this.

Comment: @M1001 . . . I added the table name to the queries.